# Lighting House Numbers without Electricity

Tags: lighting

I'm looking for ideas on how make my house number visible at night. My house numbers are attached to my mailbox. There is no power feed from my house to anywhere nearby the mailbox and there is a driveway in the way. So running copper isn't an option.

My initial idea is to paint the house numbers in glow-in-the-dark paint. The mailbox gets lots of afternoon sun, so that perfect for 'recharging' the paint. My worry for the idea is that most of the GitD paints are craft grade and won't last long in a directly exposed outdoor environment.

So my question is does anybody have any recommendations for GitD outdoor paint or have another idea completely that would work for my situation?

Comment: Open-ended questions like this aren't ideal on DIYSE. We're not a discussion forum. Product recommendations are also off topic. Please do your own research and come back with specific questions about your chosen approach.

Comment: I will point out that inexpensive solar/battery systems are a dime a dozen these days. A little backlighting could be magic. Take garden lights, for example. If you were ok with the short duration of glow paint, those would be more than adequate as illumination for several hours in the evening.

Comment: You can buy pre-made, pre-painted glow-in-the-dark house numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GITD products just don't GITD very long - by the time the sun has set, most of the "charge" from the sun has gone.

So, **Solar lights** are the obvious normal solution. Of course, they involve electricity. And batteries or ultracapacitors, and short, local wires.

**Reflective numbers** is the *obvious normal even simpler solution* for things you *mostly* want visible at night to things that have headlights. Are you really *particularly* looking for "house number visible to people walking/riding/driving at night with no lights?

[Tritium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium) offers GITD that fades very slowly and requires no charging. But it's a silly and very abnormal and slightly radioactive option for mailbox numbers.